# Reading dynamic data from binary file

Tags: c#

I have objects in my application which may have any number of "components" attached to them:

```
public class Test() {
  public Test() {
    AddComponent<AComponent>();
    AddComponent<CComponent>();
    AddComponent<ZComponent>();
  }
}
```

In my save system, the `Test` object gets written to disk but this means I also need to save the components. I'm doing that already, but my code isn't dynamic enough for my needs.

Currently, I write a bool as to whether each component exists and if that bool is true (on read), I know to load said component.

However, we also will support user plugins and it becomes problematic to write a bool for every possible component. What if a component is added or removed? Suddenly counts don't match, etc.

I'm considering writing the class name instead, so for every component that was written, I could read in its name `BComponent`, etc. Using that I could ensure that class exists, dynamically instantiate it, etc.

Is that an acceptable solution? Are there better solutions, or problems I'm not realizing?

Comment: I would agree that purely positional is a maintenance nightmare; some kind of key-based is good, and names are simple and easy keys. I wouldn't hesitate to use that approach. The only thing I'd say is : use artificial keys, not assembly-qualified-type-name keys. The latter becomes a nightmare when assemblies change.

Comment: Use a dictionary where the key is the component name and value is the data.